# Reading file content from Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have been trying to read contents of a json file from Google Cloud Storage and encounter an error. Here is my code

```
from google.cloud import storage
import jsonclient = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket_name')
blob = bucket.get_blob('file.json')
u = blob.download_as_string()
print(u)
```

I see following error

`TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'`

pretty much lost. Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to import the `Client()`, you just have to declare it like

`client = storage.Client()`.

Use the code below to load the `JSON` file from Google Cloud Storage bucket. I have tested it myself and it is working.

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()

BUCKET_NAME = '[BUCKET_NAME]'
FILE_PATH = '[path/to/file.json]'

bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
blob = bucket.get_blob(FILE_PATH)
print('The JSON file is: ')
print(blob.download_as_string())
```

Replace the `[BUCKET_NAME]` with your bucket's name and the `[path/to/file.json]` to the path where your JSON file is located inside the bucket.

Comment: if I dont import the client its give me error of "storage not defined" other than that the issues persist. now sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: I have tested the code that is in my answer and it worked for me. I suggest you to start afresh and create a new directory, new virtual environment, enter the virtual environment, install the google.cloud library using `pip install google-cloud` command and then try the code above again. It should work this way.